Subclassing a Generic class with keyword arguments
I'm attempting to inherit from a Generic class with variadic keyword arguments in Python 3.10
from typing_extensions import Unpack, TypeVar, ParamSpec

P = ParamSpec("P")
T = TypeVar("T")

class A(Generic[P]):
    def func(self, *args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs):
        print(args)
        print(kwargs)
        return 2


class Inputs(TypedDict):
    arg1: int
    arg2: str


class B(A[Unpack(Inputs)]): # Line where mypy fails
    pass

B().func(arg1=1, arg2="Hello") 

However, mypy (1.10.0) fails this check with the following. Is there another way to implement this functionality? I've seen it be used in Callables, but I prefer to not approach it that way
error: Unpack is only valid in a variadic position


You can use Unpack[TypedDictClass] to annotate a **kwargs, but you can't use it as a ParamSpec type argument. Possible duplicates: How to specify a generic over TypedDict?, Using `Unpack` on `TypeVar`s to dynamically generate function signatures.

So as mentioned in the comments, the exact syntax you describe currently isn't supported. There are however a couple of other ways of structuring it that are syntactically very similar. I would suggest something like this:
from typing_extensions import TypeVar
from dataclasses import dataclass

T = TypeVar("T")
class A(Generic[T]):
    def func(self, settings: T):
        return 2

@dataclass
class Settings:
    arg1: int
    arg2: str

class B(A[Settings]):
    pass

B().func(Settings(arg1=1, arg2="Hello"))

Alternatively, if you need the TypedDict structure, it could be done by assigning the func as a class variable:
from typing import Callable, ClassVar, TypedDict
from typing_extensions import Unpack, TypeVar

class Inputs(TypedDict):
    arg1: int
    arg2: str

@staticmethod
def input_func(**kwargs: Unpack[Inputs]):
    return kwargs


class A:
    func: ClassVar[Callable]

class B(A):
    func = input_func


B().func(arg1=1, arg2="Hello")

Hope this helps!
